# How to render Vue component from file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a very simple component in my Vue.js app.

App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        App Component
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "App"
    };
</script>
```

Now, I try to import this component from file and render it.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Vue Js Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
import App from "./App.vue"

Vue.component("App", App);

var app = new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

However, I am not able to use this component. When I open the index.html file in my browser, I can not see my `div` from component as expected, but only my `#app` `div`. What am I doing wrong here?

I am using the latest vue.js and my browser is the latest Firefox.

Comment: Remove this line `Vue.component("App", App)` and it should work. Because you have specified the `render` method for this component.

Comment: @jom I've just tried, it doesn't work :(

Comment: It really should work, would you be able to create a verifiable fiddle for it?

Comment: But how to add App.vue file to fiddle?

Comment: Try [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) and please make a verifiable example.

Comment: Here is my [project](https://codesandbox.io/s/n7vm15ym60)

Comment: Thank you for creating it. Why do you need to add Vue via CDN though? In your CodeSandbox project, you could get it working if you add a reference to `vue` under the `Dependencies` tree.

Comment: I am not familiar with CodeSandbox, unfortunately. That's why.